# JCheckBox selecting 1st option automatically

Tags: java

I'm developing a system that, once selected a field of a `JComboBox`, change the text of a `JButton`, from connected to Offline depending on the status of the field written in the `JComboBox`.

All this has been done, but I have a problem.

When I run the program, the system automatically enters into the event `addActionListener`, not that I have ever selected a field of `JComboBox`?

Can someone give me a hand?

*Edited in from Answer*

... The block of Code (under) is was wrote into a method executed Before the comboBox.addActionListener. This code, it was wrote, beacause I have a need to popolate dinamically the elements of JComboBox...

```
private void actionOfSearch(){

table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me){

    if(ipAvailable){
        blockSetRemoteUnit = false;
        timer = new Timer(10000, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //extracted_values is a Vector<Stirng>
            if(typeOfConnection.equals("ABC") || typeOfConnection.equals("DEF"))
                extracted_values = new E_ConnectionABC_DEF(resourceSelected, credential).result;
            else{
                try {
                    extracted_values = new E_ConnectionOther(resourceSelected, credential).result;
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) { e1.printStackTrace(); }
            }
            int size = extracted_values.elementAt(0).size();
            String stringOfNameLabel = "";
            String stringValueOfResource = "";
            JLabel nameResource = null;
            JProgressBar progressBar = null;
            subPanelOfinfoServer.removeAll();
            subPanelOfinfoServer.repaint();
            subPanelOfinfoServer.revalidate();
            if(!blockSetRemoteUnit)
                comboBox.addItem(" ");
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
                stringOfNameLabel = extracted_values.elementAt(1).elementAt(i);
                //Here I popolate the fields of JComboBox, and how you can see,
                //I can Change the fields, every time that I selected a different Row
                //of the JTable.        
                if(!blockSetRemoteUnit && stringOfNameLabel.length()==2 && stringOfNameLabel.contains(":"))
                    comboBox.addItem(stringOfNameLabel);         
                nameResource = new JLabel(stringOfNameLabel);
                nameResource.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                stringValueOfResource = extracted_values.elementAt(0).elementAt(i);
                progressBar = new JProgressBar();
                progressBar.setValue(Integer.parseInt(stringValueOfResource));

                subPanelOfinfoServer.add(nameResource);
                subPanelOfinfoServer.add(progressBar);
            }
            blockSetRemoteUnit = true;
            }
       });
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.setCoalesce(true);
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.start();
    }
    else{
        logger.warn("[JTABLE-SelectRow]ATTENTION! " + resourceSelected + " is not Available");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "IP " + resourceSelected + " is not Available");
    }   
    }});
}
```

NOW, in other Java method, (that it's call After), You find this code:

```
private JPanel connectResource(){
    JPanel remoteResource = new JPanel();
    JPanel panelSouth = new JPanel();
    //jstMpd is a Vector<Vector<String>>
    jstMpd  = getAlreadyMapped();
    remoteResource.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    final JButton ResourceConnect = new JButton();

    comboBox.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Object lettereReadComboBox = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
            final String letter = lettereReadComboBox.toString();

            try {
                alreadyMapped = ctrIfalreadyMapped(ResourceSelected, letter, typeOfConnection, jstMpd);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            }

            if(alreadyMapped)
                ResourceConnect.setIcon(new ImageIcon(path + "src/img/Disconnect.png"));
            else
                ResourceConnect.setIcon(new ImageIcon(path + "src/img/Drive-Network-Connected.png"));

            ResourceConnect.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    try {
                        alreadyMapped = ctrIfalreadyMapped(ResourceSelected, letter, typeOfConnection, jstMpd);
                    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e1) {
                    }
                    if(alreadyMapped){
                        try {
                            String localLetterMounted = deleteElement(ResourceSelected, letter, jstMpd);
                            if(localLetterMounted!=""){
                                new E_Mapped_Drives().unmountResource(localLetterMounted);
                                ResourceConnect.setIcon(new ImageIcon(path + "src/img/Drive-Network-Connected.png"));
                                ResourceConnect.setActionCommand("!alreadyMapped");
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) { 
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You didn't selected any Letter of Remote Resource!\n Please Re-Try");
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        String letterGetted = "";
                        String letterMounted= "";
                        if(typeOfConnection.equals("RDP") || typeOfConnection.equals("VNC")){
                            try {
                                letterGetted = letter;
                                letterMounted = new E_Mapped_Drives().mountResourceWindows(ResourceSelected, letterGetted, credential);
                                jstMpd.addElement(new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList(letterGetted, ResourceSelected,typeOfConnection,letterMounted)));
                                ResourceConnect.setIcon(new ImageIcon(path + "src/img/Disconnect.png"));
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                logger.warn("[BOTTONE-ResourceCONNECT][IOException] You didn't selected any letter!");
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You didn't selected any Letter of Remote Resource!\n Please Re-Try");
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            try {
                                letterGetted = new E_Mapped_Drives().mountResourceLinux(ResourceSelected, credential);//, comboBox.getSelectedItem(), credential);
                                ResourceConnect.setIcon(new ImageIcon(path + "src/img/Disconnect.png"));
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You didn't selected any Letter of Remote Resource!\n Please Re-Try");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    panelSouth.setBackground(getColorBackground());
    remoteResource.add(comboBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    remoteResource.add(ResourceConnect, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    remoteResource.add(panelSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    return remoteResource;
}
```

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to copy-paste your code to a *new project* and make sure it compiles and runs before posting it here.

Comment: Please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question on StackOverflow, in particular provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example). You can edit your question to provide one. GL.

Comment: Hi JoeJoe, I've edited in your addendum that was posted as an answer; I have also voted to close this because it does not follow the FAQ about how to ask a _good_ question. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit] this post. After that, you may ask the the question be reopened. Please add in any stack traces or exceptions or errors you are having, and post only the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are creating your action listener BEFORE adding items do the JComboBox, OR programmatically selecting some value of the combo box after registering the action istener.
Create your action listener after all the items are added into the JComboBox.

This happens because if a combobox has no items, when you add an item it becomes the selected value, firing the action listener.

Comment: Thanks you, but I'm sure to having initialization(JComboBox) before my ActionListener(JComboBox). I Could check this, when I run the code in debug mode.

Comment: Can you check if you are not programmatically selecting some value of the combo box after registering the action istener?

Comment: Also can you provide your code?

Comment: I've found the problem. I've called a listener, within another.